# is_alive() in python3.6.8 is not waiting for the thread to get over

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, python-3.6

I am facing an issue with python upgrade from 3.4 to 3.6.8, where my multithreading code is not giving result as expected.

I am using is_alive() method to check if my thread is still alive, but with the upgrade of python version to 3.6.8 is does not wait.

EDIT: Code added

```
class ABC(Thread):
  @csrf_exempt 
  def __init__(self, req):

        super(ABC, self).__init__()

    @csrf_exempt
    def run(self):
           <code block>


abc = ABC(request)
abc.start()

if abc.is_alive():
    print("waiting")
    abc.join()
```

Any help here will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Sunil

Comment: Could you please add the code.

Comment: @Mntfr : Added code, Please have a look. Thanks